# How to write alternative code "document.querySelector" in Angular 2 (TypeScript)?

Tags: angular, typescript

I am using Angular 2 (TypeScript). I want to rewrite the code below.

```
<video></video>

var video = document.querySelector("video");
video.src = URL.createObjectURL(localMediaStream);
video.play();
```

However, I don't know any way to get "video" in Angular 2. This is so far what I did.

```
<video [src]="videoSrc"></video>

videoSrc:string;
…
this.videoSrc = URL.createObjectURL(stream);
// Since I don't know any way to get "video",
// do I have any way to use video.play() here?
```

Comment: Late comment . . . I know the answer about @ViewChild works for this case, but if someone really needed to do querySelector, I would think that 
```constructor(private el: ElementRef) { const result = this.el.nativeElement.querySelector('.myClass'); }``` would be better than 
```const result = document.querySelector('.myClass'); ``` 
as in https://angular.io/guide/attribute-directives, though https://angular.io/api/core/ElementRef says "Use this API as the last resort."

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can get a reference to the `video` element by using a local variable and `@ViewChild`

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template : `<video #my-video></video>`
})
export class App implements AfterViewInit {

  // myVideo == #my-video
  @ViewChild('myVideo') myVideo: any;

  afterViewInit() {
    let video = this.myVideo.nativeElement;
    video.src = URL.createObjectURL(yourBlob);
    video.play();
  }
```

Here's a [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/Na2F8oFmrVm1WgEjoBxM?p=preview) demonstrating the case (*the plnkr differs a little bit, since I couldn't load a video, apparently it's no that simple, instead I load an image as the poster for video tag. You'll get the idea*)

**Update**

You deleted your last comment, but it was a valid question since the [docs only specify one way](https://angular.io/docs/js/latest/api/core/ViewChild-var.html) of using `@ViewChild`.The docs use the type to query for the children, but you can also use a string. See in [`ViewChildMetadata#L327`](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/modules/angular2/src/core/metadata/di.ts#L347) that it accepts a Type (Component/Directive) or a string.

**Update 2**

Actually the docs show this alternative, but it's in another part of it. Under [`Query`](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/Query-var.html) docs you can see it. Note that `Query` is deprecated, but the syntax is still valid for `ViewChild/ViewChildren` and `ContentChild/ContentChildren`.

Comment: Hi, Eric. The only thing I found about ViewChild is angular.io/docs/js/latest/api/core/ViewChild-var.html. But the code there looks so different. Any other place I can learn ViewChild? Thanks!

Comment: Ha, actually I want to change my question, since I cannot edit my comment after 5 min I post there. So I deleted it and created again :) Thanks again!

Comment: For new Angular versions (>= 17.2) the approach with signals would be:
https://angular.dev/guide/signals/queries#viewchild

Answer (score 0):

In Angular, you typically don't use document.querySelector directly. Instead, you use Angular's built-in directives and services. For instance, you can use the ViewChild decorator to get the first element or the directive matching the selector from the view DOM. If the DOM element is not directly linked to an Angular component, you can use the Renderer2 service.

Here's an example of using

ViewChild:

```js
import { Component, ViewChild, ElementRef, AfterViewInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `<div #myDiv>Some content</div>`
})
export class AppComponent implements AfterViewInit {
  @ViewChild('myDiv') myDiv: ElementRef;

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    console.log(this.myDiv.nativeElement.innerHTML);
  }
}
```

And here's an example of using

Renderer2:

```js
import { Component, Renderer2, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `<div>Some content</div>`
})
export class AppComponent {
  constructor(private renderer: Renderer2, private el: ElementRef) {
    const div = this.renderer.selectRootElement('div');
    console.log(div.innerHTML);
  }
}
```

Remember, direct DOM manipulation in Angular is not a good practice. We should always try to use Angular's built-in methods and services for interacting with the DOM.