# How to play mp3 with Angular 2?

Tags: angular, ionic2

I want to write a small ionic/angular application where I load a dynamic mp3 file from a remote server and play it for pressing a button OR if it is checked I play it automaticly. I tried to use the simple `<audio></audio>` but i am not sure if this is the good way for this...

*code:*

**html**

```
<audio id="player">
<source id="source" src="http://remote.address.com/example.mp3"></source>
</audio>
```

**javascript**

```
play(){
var audio= document.getElementById('player');
audio.play();
}
```

Comment: The most angular2 way to do this, is to grab the `audio` element with a variable, like in this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33771672/4933038). Remember, all this is javascript, so don't be afraid of using it :)

Comment: I thought angular2 and ionic2 are more simmilar :( no @ViewChild in ionic or I should import something?

Comment: I don't know about Ionic2 nor Ionic1. You included angular2 in your tags and the question title asks only about angular2, so that would do it. But for your case I couldn't say, it's not just angular2, sorry :/

Comment: It was working... I just leaved an ( ) from the html so the function was not even called :) thanks!

Comment: PS:- for some reason i got error in same code, resolved by simply removing `</source>` and adding `/>` at the end of source tag

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You can create a new Audio element in the Javascript code ... not in HTML

for example :

```
var audio = new Audio();
audio.src = "http://remote.address.com/example.mp3";
audio.load();
audio.play();
```

Comment: does this creates element in background or in html? I mean to put play and pause button. how can that be done.. or we can just use triggers to play and pause using this?

Comment: it creates it in the background if you want to pause it you can use the pause function audio
 audio.pause();

check out the Media element API : 

[link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement)

Comment: may i have working example for the same ? something like plunkr or snippet ?

Answer (score 3):

If you want run sound in Ionic-2 / Angular-2 mobile application .

[Follow **Ionic 2** guide here](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/native-audio/)

Install:

```
ionic plugin add --save cordova-plugin-nativeaudio
npm install --save @ionic-native/native-audio
```

Usage:

```
import { NativeAudio } from '@ionic-native/native-audio';

    constructor(private nativeAudio: NativeAudio) { }



    this.nativeAudio.preloadSimple('uniqueId1','path/to/file.mp3').then(onSuccess, onError);
    this.nativeAudio.preloadComplex('uniqueId2','path/to/file2.mp3', 1, 1, 0).then(onSuccess, onError);

    this.nativeAudio.play('uniqueId1').then(onSuccess, onError);

    // can optionally pass a callback to be called when the file is done playing
    this.nativeAudio.play('uniqueId1', () =>console.log('uniqueId1 is done playing'));
```

[source-1 : https://stackoverflow.com/a/43917441/6786941](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43917441/6786941)

Comment: but in debug it load the file via http

Answer (score 0):

I have tried @reba's answer but it didn't work on mobile browsers or may be there are Autoplay policies which are stopping to play the Audio files. So I have created and `audio` element and modify the `src` dynamically like,

```
<audio id="player">
   <source></source>
</audio>
```

In Angular,

```
play(){
   let audio= document.getElementById('player');
   audio.src = "http://remote.address.com/example.mp3";
   audio.load();
   audio.play();
}
```

Note: If you don't want to show the audio tag on page, then you can make it `[hidden]`