# Angular2: restart the html audio tag on real time

Tags: html, angular

I have a component which play an mp3 file, and it gets the played file name from its parent. Here is the code:

```
export class PlayComponent implements OnChanges  {

      @Input() fileToPlay:string;

      ngOnChanges(arg){

         console.log(arg.fileToPlay);
      }
    }
```

and the html is:

```
<div *ngIf="fileToPlay!=''">
    <audio  controls autoplay class="playa" di="audio">
      <source [src]="fileToPlay" type="audio/mpeg">
      Your browser does not support the audio element.
    </audio>
</div>
```

It works fine for first play. The value of `fileToPlay` may change and i want to play the new file on real time, but **it always play the first file name.**

How can i fix it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to check by changing your Component and HTML as below :

//Your Component

```
import { Component, Input, OnChanges, SimpleChange } from '@angular/core';

export class PlayComponent implements OnChanges  {

  private showPlayer: boolean = false; 
  @Input() fileToPlay:string;

  ngOnInit(){
    if (this.fileToPlay != '') {
      this.showPlayer = true;
    }
  }

  ngOnChanges(changes: {[propKey: string]: SimpleChange}){

     if(changes['fileToPlay'].previousValue !== changes['fileToPlay'].currentValue && changes['fileToPlay'].currentValue !== '') {
      this.showPlayer = false;
      setTimeout(() => this.showPlayer = true, 0);
    }
  }
}
```

// HTML

```
<div *ngIf="showPlayer">
  <audio  controls autoplay class="playa" di="audio">
    <source [src]="fileToPlay" type="audio/mpeg">
    Your browser does not support the audio element.
  </audio>
</div>
```

Comment: No, i am not checking for change every second. What i am doing is, when any change happen i will check `fileToPlay` variables `previous` and `current` value if both are different and not empty then i am setting `showPlayer` to `false` which will hide your player and after `0` millisecond of time out i am setting `showPlayer` to `true` which will display player again. Here timeout is `0` which will display player and recreates it in a blink of an eye.

Answer (score 12):

I know this is old but I had the same problem and the only thing that worked for me was putting the src in the audio not the source:

```
<audio controls src={{filetoplay}}></audio>
```

couldn't find anything on google so figured it out myself, hope it helps someone

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the HTML Element, you can use directly javascript to manipulate audio. See this post : [How to play mp3 with Angular 2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33859270/how-to-play-mp3-with-angular-2)