# Ionic 3 with Angular 5 node.js play an audio on button click

Tags: javascript, node.js, ionic3, angular5

I`m stuck in a situation where i have to play an audio from assets folder in my project on button click.

here is my html code

```
<ion-header>
<ion-navbar color = "primary">
 <ion-title>

 Norrani Qaida
</ion-title>
 </ion-navbar>
   </ion-header>



  <ion-content >


   <button class = "button" ng-click = "playAudio()">PLAY</button>


   </ion-content>
```

here is my .ts controller code

```
    import { Component } from '@angular/core';
    import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';
    import { AboutPage } from '../about/about';
    import { NativeAudio } from '@ionic-native/native-audio';

    @Component({
     selector: 'page-home',
     templateUrl: 'home.html'
   })
   export class HomePage {


   constructor() {


 }
   }
```

anyone here helps me to write playaudio() function in controller to play an audio on button click from assets in project

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to play mp3 with Angular 2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33859270/how-to-play-mp3-with-angular-2)

Answer (score 0):

Since you have already imported NativeAudio, its very easy. Just do this:

```
constructor(private nativeAudio: NativeAudio) { 
       this.nativeAudio.preloadSimple('uniqueId1', 'path/to/file.mp3').then(onSuccess, onError);
}

playAudio () {
  this.nativeAudio.play('uniqueId1').then(onSuccess, onError);
}
```

[Source](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/native-audio/)

Comment: Not Working ! :(

Comment: 1.Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[HomePage -> NativeAudio]:

2. Error: StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[HomePage -> NativeAudio]: 

these errors are encountered

Comment: You need to add NativeAudio in your providers array in AppModule