# ng2 @ViewChild(ren) / @ContentChild(ren) in plain JS?

Tags: typescript, angular

I recently started using [ViewChildren and ContentChildren](http://blog.mgechev.com/2016/01/23/angular2-viewchildren-contentchildren-difference-viewproviders) in Angular 2, but had now been wondering if these could be used in ES6 without TypeScript annotations as well.

The TypeScript syntax, as per the [docs](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/ViewChild-var.html), is as follows:

```
@ViewChild(ItemDirective) viewChild: ItemDirective;
```

Alternatively, as per [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33770902/how-to-write-alternative-code-document-queryselector-in-angular-2-typescript):

```
// myVideo == #my-video
@ViewChild('myVideo') myVideo: any;
```

Now, the corresponding [source](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/2.0.0-beta.3/modules/angular2/src/core/metadata/di.ts#L337-L339) has Metadata classes for ViewChild and co., which I recall could be used to add some of the other annotations in plain JS. So I'm thinking it should be doable, but I'm not really sure how in this case. Would anyone be able to shed some light on this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that such decorators should work with ES6 / ES7 (you need to include ES7 decorators in addition to ES6 itself). The latter does have are class and property decorators so you should be able to transpile the `ViewChild` decorator.

It's not the same for parameter decorators that aren't supported...

See this answer and its comments:

- [Angular 2: How Should We Be Handling Dependency Injection with ES6/ES7?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35089037/angular-2-how-should-we-be-handling-dependency-injection-with-es6-es7/35089483#35089483)

This link could be also useful:

- https://medium.com/google-developers/exploring-es7-decorators-76ecb65fb841#.p4uu6y19c

Comment: Thanks, this is hella interesting; the babel plugins/transformers mentioned there just allowed me to convert all of my TS to ES6/7... except for one line. Ironically that's exactly my one `@ViewChild` line. :( That does actually seem like it could be a bug though, so perhaps I should also try and file an issue at [`babel-plugin-angular2-annotations`](https://github.com/shuhei/babel-plugin-angular2-annotations)... If that lib does still get this done, then consider this solved.

Comment: Couldn't edit my comment anymore, but now filed it [on there](https://github.com/shuhei/babel-plugin-angular2-annotations/issues/18).

Comment: I noticed the decorator wasn't able to take variables, and eventually found that the working TypeScript transpilation just used `Reflect.decorate`. I ended up just calling that now; since it allows variables it's the only solution so far that fulfills my requirements (though a tad more verbose), while being cool with JS too. Thanks.